# IOS weight scale pointer rotates abruptedly

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, core-animation

I am requested to make an application, displaying the data on a virtual scale face animatedly. The data is obtained from `BLE` HW scale over `BT 4.0`. App scale face is designed just as a real watch, with the pointer rotating to indicate the data. As a note,  the data from HW seems to be dis-contiguous. I am sure that's caused by the irregular data sampling of HW.  Here is my design : make a queue and queue the incoming data. Then consume the data in a timer and dispatch animation  That's the primary background knowledge. Currently, I am stuck in the problem of abruptly rotating the pointer as the real one. I have tried several solutions but none of them is acceptable to customers. I suppose that it is closely related to the poor user experience of pointer animation stuff. Please help me on the following question.

I try to invoke `CATransform3DMakeRotation` in the timer (50ms) to make the animation of rotation, the pointer always slightly trembles when it rotates. I suppose it is caused by the fact that a new animation is dispatched while the previous animation is not completed. This conclusion can be verified by the fact that the increasing the timer frequency causes the more seriously trembling while the decreasing recovers. Then I am trying invoke the next rotation in the completion callback when the last one is done. Now the trembling really disappears. but the rotation is not contiguous visually. Suppose 0, 450, 500, 600. Then rotation looks like consisting of 3 sub-animations (0~450, 450 ~500 and 500 ~600). That also gives rise to the poor experience.

So, How can I deal with it?

Please help to enlighten me. Thanks